# How to manually delete DartEditor Files directory or make changes to it

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I have pointed/opened dart folder, so. that, where Darteditors own program-files are, in Darteditors File window and begin to create one web program there. Clever? Is'nt it?:)
I wanted to test one of my own programs there, for using pub packages.

Now editor seems stucked, nothing works, can open FEEDBACK window only for 2 seconds and i can close Editor only with Windows Operations control.
Might there be some kind of recursion going? 
New install is quick, but finding the course of this would be useful..

So how can I clean this DartEditors Files-directory without starting DartEditor?
And should I avoid putting my own program files in dart folder?

I have latest Darteditor, 19425, in Windows7.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid putting any of your own code into the Editor's directory; that directory is managed by our auto-update process and you could potentially loose that code.

To get your Editor back to a happy state, you'll have to delete its workspace metadata folder. On windows, that should be in c:\Users\yourname\DartEditor. Just delete it (or rename it) and the Editor should be able to start back up again.

Going forward, you'll want to locate your code outside the Editor's directory; we default to c:\Users\username\dart. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, good information! I have tried to keep my dart files away from "c:\Users\yourname\DartEditor -folder", "Home of eternal destruction". In Public folder I have better control and backup systems to all data. But that caused some problems before I learned this dart settings system.  I also had two older versions of metadata, and old settings pomped occasionally from there to DartEditor. Now my DartEditor is.. in happy state.